# Did the US government spend millions of dollars to train Chinese prostitutes to drink responsibly?

Tags: united-states, government, alcohol, china, prostitution

According to [this site](http://dirtyspendingsecrets.com/), "Washington is spending $2.6 million training Chinese prostitutes to drink more responsibly on the job." Is this true, and, if so, what program are they referencing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"[T]raining...to drink more responsibly," is not an accurate summary of the grant's use, as the summary does not include the central topic of the grant, which was the study of and mitigation of AIDS transmission.

> Dr. Li’s project will develop, implement and evaluate a venue-based alcohol and HIV risk reduction intervention center for establishment-based female sex workers in Guangxi, China. "

http://prognosis.med.wayne.edu/article/grant-allows-research-to-study-link-between-alcohol-abuse-and-spread-of-hiv

Comment: I've removed all comments, the political aspect is completely off-topic here.

Comment: The alcohol reduction portion will be interesting, since most Asians lack the ability to metabolize alcohol efficiently - which is why they get drunk quicker.

Comment: @Darwy: "Most" is pushing it; the [alcohol flush reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_flush_reaction) is present in 36% of East Asians (Chinese, Japanese, Koreans), and that's where it's most prevalent. It's not a majority anywhere. It's also somewhat self-limiting; alcoholism is a harder habit to develop when you reliably develop super-hangovers from indulging.